# Want to get the name of month in form of Jan, Mar, .... Dec. using JS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

```
  var today = new Date();
  //$('#timeStampID').val(today.getFullYear() + '-' + 
    ('0' + (today.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + 
    today.getDate()).slice(-2));
  $('#timeStampID').val(String(('0' + 
    today.getDate()).slice(-2)) + ' ' + 
    String(('0' + (today.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)) + ' ' + 
    String(today.getFullYear()));
```

*Here i'm getting output on input filed as : 23 04 2018* but i want to show Apr in place of 04 i.e name of the month

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code for future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a method for this built into the Date object. But you can do something like this:

```
var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

var monthName = months[today.getMonth()];
```